# doi problem with model3-num-names.bst of elsarticle

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, elsarticle, doi

I am using 'elsarticle.cls', 'model3-num-names.bst' and 'numcompress.sty'
*mytex.tex* goes as:

```
\documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nodots]{numcompress}
\begin{document}
\cite{bull_comparison_2013}
\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

and *mybib.bib* goes as:

```
@article{bull_comparison_2013,
title = {A comparison of multi-scale 3D {X}-ray tomographic inspection techniques for assessing carbon fibre composite impact damage},
volume = {75},
issn = {0266-3538},
url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0266353812004137},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.compscitech.2012.12.006},
journal = {Composites Science and Technology},
author = {Bull, D. J. and Helfen, L. and Sinclair, I. and Spearing, S. M. and Baumbach, T.},
year = {2013},
keywords = {X-ray computed tomography},
pages = {55 -- 61}
}
```

but the 4 steps compiled pdf gose as:

[image: AnnoyingDOI]

**Why there is a "\bibinfo{doi}" before the real doi?**
**How can I remove that?**

Comment: Maybe try with `doi = {10.1016/j.compscitech.2012.12.006},`? If this does not help, please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: No, it is not working. MWEB is added. Please help.

Comment: If I run your example, I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byd7C.png. (with the file from https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0007/56842/elsarticle-template.zip) Which tex distribution are you using? Which version of `numcompress` and `model3-num-names.bst` are you using?

Comment: With `doi = {10.1016/j.compscitech.2012.12.006},` the output becomes https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrNZl.png

Comment: Problem solved with template.zip. Thank you. btw, I have being using [link](www.latextemplates.com/templates/academic_journals/1/elsarticle.zip). it is not working some how. maybe i got it from wrong source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @samcarter, I replaced my 'model3-num-names.bst' with one from [els template](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0007/56842/elsarticle-template.zip). My problem is solved.